# how to reopen the stdout file after closing all the descriptors?

Tags: c

I am having a problem in daemonize program. The problem is after closing all the opened descriptors, i need to reopen the stdout file to print the message.

I am having one way. But that is not working.

The way is duplicate the stdout descriptor using dup and reopen that. But the deamonize function is called it closes all the file descriptors. So, that duplicate file descriptor is also closed.

Can anyone please help me to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to print to stdout in a daemon?

Comment: I want to check the program is running only once(single instance daemon). So, if it is already executed i need to print the error message in terminal.

Comment: This question may be related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084099/re-opening-stdout-and-stdin-file-descriptors-after-closing-them)

Comment: stack overflow link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084099/re-opening-stdout-and-stdin-file-descriptors-after-closing-them

Comment: @msc, It is not that question. My requirement is after closing all the file descriptors, i need to open the stdout file.

Comment: You can try to open `/dev/tty`.

Comment: It is not working. It gives the error "no such devices or address".

Comment: @suresh - see related link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908687/how-to-redirect-the-output-back-to-the-screen-after-freopenout-txt-a-stdo

Comment: @suresh Do that before calling `daemon()`.

Comment: @msc, That is ok. But before doing that i Want to close all the opened file descriptor. So, that duplicate file descriptors also closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `daemon()` to daemonize, you can specify `noclose` to prevent these filedescriptors from being closed:

```
daemon(0, 1);
```

But you should close these after your check by hand, otherwise your terminals might get messed up.